Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
I have a problem when I run my job on GitHub.
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
This is my .yaml file.
main.yaml
name: Java CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up JDK
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'temurin'

      - name: Check if ChromeDriver is installed
        run: chromedriver --version || echo "ChromeDriver is not installed"

      - name: Check if Chrome is installed
        run: google-chrome --version || echo "Chrome is not installed"

      - name: Cache the Maven packages to speed up build
        uses: actions/cache@v2 # Update to v2
        with:
          path: ~/.m2
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-m2-${{ hashFiles('**/pom.xml') }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-m2

      - name: Build with Maven
        run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml

      - name: Run tests
        run: mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @Test"

I'm using this serenity.properties file for my driver but for some reason, the GitHub doesn't detect my driver.
serenity.properties
serenity.project.name=SELENIUM FRAMEWORK
serenity.test.root=org.example
webdriver.driver=chrome
webdriver.autodownload=true
serenity.browser.maximized=true
serenity.use.unique.browser=false
serenity.restart.browser.each.scenario=true



Hope you can help me,
Thank you in advance.
